# Vim: What's the best way to have markdown automatically enabled for comments?

Tags: vim, markdown

I would like to be able to format comments in code somewhat:

```
# **TODO**
#
# *Don't forget*
```

I want markdown syntax to be highlighted a bit but only in comments, add `cterm=bold` for `\*\*(.*)\*\*` or something.

Is there a way to do it in Vim?

Comment: It's probably possible with things like `:call matchadd("Function", "\\*\\*[^\*]*\\*\\*")` but… the whole point of Markdown, similar languages and the email/BBS conventions they are based on is to convey meaning *without* "enrichment".

Comment: Yep but still it looks so much nicer with *some* enrichment

Answer (score 1):

To do this properly, you'd have to `:syntax include` the markdown syntax into each individual syntax (that has comments that you're interested in), and have it `containedin=` the corresponding syntax group for comments. That's doable, but requires some effort (depending on how many and which syntaxes to modify).

It's quicker to use a plugin like my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) to change the syntax of those comment blocks to markdown (manually, and on demand). With a corresponding mapping, this can be set up quite easily (but it's not automatic as the first alternative).